# Keep picturebox's edges in the edge of the panel

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, picturebox

The black one, is a picture box inside a maximized panel..
Whenever I drag the picture box, it just drags to where I want.
[image]

However, I want it like this
[image]
Whenever the picturebox's edge reached the edge of the panel, it would stop dragging. Simply because there is no picture to be shown, so I don't want the user to see the form behind.

**EDIT:** Here is my mousemove Event

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        Dim Pos As Point = Me.PointToClient(MousePosition)
        Pos.Offset(Offset.X, Offset.Y)
        PictureBox1.Location = Pos
    End If       
End Sub
```

Comment: Well it depends how your code for dragging is! Inside MouseMove event handler you may even simply check if pictureBox.Bounds is inside panel.ClientRectangle.

Comment: [This link have my answer][1] I made another better question like this. Please see link.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131721/keep-pictureboxs-corner-outside-the-bounds-of-the-panel