# keep pictureBox's corner outside the bounds of the panel

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, panel, picturebox

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    If (e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left) Then
        Me.PictureBox1.Location = New Point((Me.pbpos.X + (Control.MousePosition.X - Me.offset.X)), _
                                            (Me.pbpos.Y + (Control.MousePosition.Y - Me.offset.Y)))
    End If
End Sub
```

This is the picture, not yet dragged. Ofcourse it does not fit the screen, although the top and the left side is the edges of the picture. (the gray color is the panel)
[image]

Now if I drag it up to the left this is how it looks like..
[image]
This scenario is **just OK** since the picture is really big that's why I need to be able to drag it.. As you can see at the bottom right, now, the panel is to be seen because I dragged the picture too much in the upper left(which is not right)

Now, what I really want is for it to look like this..
[image]
When I do drag, like *picture #2* I want the edges of the picture to stay right there. The user now, must not be able to drag it further to the upper left since that is the last part of the picture (*technically, the user must not be able to see the background which is the panel*) same thing applied to the other side.

Hope this is much clearer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    If (e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left) Then

        Dim x As Integer = (Me.pbpos.X + (Control.MousePosition.X - Me.offset.X))
        Dim y As Integer = (Me.pbpos.Y + (Control.MousePosition.Y - Me.offset.Y))

        x = Math.Min(Math.Max(x, -(Me.PictureBox1.Width - Me.Panel1.Right)), 0)
        y = Math.Min(Math.Max(y, -(Me.PictureBox1.Height - Me.Panel1.Bottom)), 0)

        Me.PictureBox1.Location = New Point(x, y)

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: No Sir, you are doing it the other way around, sorry for my lack of explanation. I need the corner of the picturebox, not to go past through inside the panel, but able to go outside the panel.

Comment: I am really happy that you are helping me, although you don't get my question. lol First, I am able to drag the picture to whichever place I want it to be. However, thus the picture go *outside* the bounds of panel, its perfectly okay, as long as the picture's edges does **NOT** go inside the bounds of the panel.

Comment: No, I clearly don't understand you question. Read your title: `"keep pictureBox's corner to the edge of the panel"`. Which edge? Left, top, right, bottom? All? Do you want it do stick? Or just not surpass? Please edit your question cause I still don't know what you mean. Also, consider change your images.

Comment: More like it, though its only effective on the right and bottom edges. How about the top and left? I tried adding the same code for top and left, but nothing happened?

Comment: @AdorableVB It's simple, just do `Math.Min(x/y, 0)`. I've updated the answer.